# KL Divergence of two continuous circles.

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

So, I need to compute the KL Divergence between two two dimensional normal distributions.. So, say one is mean=mp, std=stdp, the other is mean=mq, std=stdq and I guess I want to compute

$\displaystyle{\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }P(x,y) (\log
   (P(x,y))-\log (Q(x,y)))dy\ dx}$

Where

$P(x,y) = \displaystyle{\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\text{mp})^2}{2 \text{stdp}^2}-\frac{(y-\text{mp})^2}{2
   \text{stdp}^2}}}{2 \pi  \text{stdp}^2}}$

and
$Q(x,y) = \displaystyle{\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\text{mq})^2}{2 \text{stdq}^2}-\frac{(y-\text{mq})^2}{2
   \text{stdq}^2}}}{2 \pi  \text{stdq}^2}}$

Can someone please tell me how/if there's a way to compute this without numeric integration?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232210/quadratic-functon-integration-over-normal-distribution

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that!